# 404/500 error with Ajax call in Rails 3.2 app (routes checked)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, validation, http-status-code-404

I am trying to write an Ajax call that will check to see if the email address a user has input into the form is already in the database. I have checked and double-checked my routes and can't figure out the problem here. There are multiple similar SO questions but in most of them it seemed like the problem was that someone defined a route as `get` in `routes.rb` but made the Ajax call with `post` or vice versa. The error that I'm getting is: `POST http://localhost:3000/registrations/validate_uniqueness 404 (Not Found)`

```
routes.rb

post '/registrations/validate_uniqueness' => 'registrations#validate_uniqueness'
```

...

```
registrations_controller.rb

  def validate_uniqueness
    if User.find_by_email(params[:email])
      render :json => { value: true }
    else
      render :json => { value: false }
    end
  end
```

...

```
Ajax call, when successful should assign a boolean value to the `exists` variable

function validateUserFields() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/registrations/validate_uniqueness",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {email: $("#user_email").val()},
    success: function() {
      var exists = value;
      alert(value);
    },
    error: alert("Error!")
  })
...
```

***update***
I changed the controller action to look like this:

```
  def validate_uniqueness
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        if User.find_by_email(params[:email])
          render :json => { value: true }
        else
          render :json => { value: false }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Still getting 404 error

***Second Edit***
Figured out how to use Chrome's dev tools to see more info about my Ajax request. This is the full error message, from Devise:

```
Unknown action

Could not find devise mapping for path "/registrations/validate_uniqueness".This may happen for two reasons:1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

So I changed `routes.rb` to:

```
  devise_scope :user do 
    post '/registrations/validate_uniqueness' => 'registrations#validate_uniqueness'
  end
```

It was a step in the right direction but now I'm getting:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined`

Comment: You forgot an ‘end' clause on validate_uniqueness method. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that and added a fourth `end`. Still getting the errors!

Comment: Could you print local web server logging output? How do you start your app?

Comment: Just added that output to the end of the post

Comment: yes, made that change. now I'm having trouble handling the response or something, because it tells me that `value` is undefined (tried defining in that my controller action during the `render json` line), and also that `response` and `result` are undefined

Comment: Replace `success: function() {` with `success: function(data) {`, so you could then do `alert(data.value)` instead defining `exists` variable.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. Now the Ajax call is working successfully. Only problem now is I need to define a `unique` (previously `exists`) variable and then be able to use it outside of this function in my validation `if...else if...else` block. I removed `var` bc I thought that would make it a global variable. the variable can be accessed in my console but getting `undefined` error when I try to use it in my actual validations

Comment: Put `var` outside and above the function block. @sixty4bit

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the controller if you only want a success/fail response:

```
def validate_uniqueness
  if User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    head :no_content   # returns 204 NO CONTENT and triggers success callback
  else 
    head :not_found    # returns 404 NOT FOUND and triggers error callback
  end
end
```

Then remove any references to a response value in JS because there will be nothing but an HTTP status code (204).

Using 404 to indicate an unsuccessful lookup is a sensible response. You should use it.